# Does the Markdown editor use a custom undo stack?

Tags: support, editor, technical

We are building a similar editor and we find it challenging to implement shortcuts such as "Cmd / Ctrl + B" (for bold) without breaking the default undo stack.

We were wondering if you have managed to do it.

Comment: Did you check the [open-source code base](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71825/158100)?

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise that its source was open.